# Get value from each select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Blocks are created through a loop, there is a select in each block. Tell me how when clicking on a button, take the selected values from all created selects?

I tried join ref to select, and v-model, but not one of them is working properly

```
<div v-for="attribute in attributes" class="col">
         {{ attribute.name }}
        <select ref="selectedVariation" class="form-control">
                 <option selected>---</option>
                 <option v-for="variation in attribute.variations"
                         :key="variation.id"
                         :value="variation.id">
                   {{ variation.name }}
                  </option>
         </select>
 </div>
<button class="btn btn-success" @click="addItemToCart()">Test</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried join ref to select, and v-model, but not one of them is working properly

Comment: @ДанилПодопригора please edit your question with what you have tried so far

Comment: thx for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Данил and welcome to stack overflow. There's not enough detail in the question to provide an exact solution, but the following hints might get you started. Also, there are several different approaches that could work; this is just one possibility.

First, include a property in the attributes objects that can be used to track the selected value, perhaps calling it `.selected`.

```
data: {
    attributes: [
        {name: "Name 1", selected: null, variations: [/*...*/]},
        {name: "Name 2", selected: null, variations: [/*...*/]},
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Second, tell Vue about that property using the `v-model` directive:

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    v-model="attribute.selected"
>
```

Then, when the button is clicked, the code can simply read the appropriate values:

```
methods: {
    addItemToCart() {
        // get an array of variation.id values
        selectedArray = this.attributes.map(attribute => attribute.selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I came to a different decision, take a look here
Add <select ref='selectedVaration' ...>
and in my method i called this.$refs.selectedVariation[i]['value']

Comment: Yep. That can work as well. There is a potential gotcha; it _might_ be relevant in your case. When Vue creates an array for a particular reference, it does not guarantee that the order of the elements in the array matches the order of the elements in the DOM. For example, it's possible that `this.$refs.selectedVariation[2]` might return the value for the first or second `<select>` rather than the third. See [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952#issuecomment-280661367) from Evan.

Comment: I checked, in my case, all created selects are required, so there will be no error, I get the values by clicking on the button of already filled selects